# Refering other modules class which has other scala version

Tags: java, scala, sbt, ivy

I have 2 modules. API and Calculator

API is depend on scala version 2.12.8 and calculator depend on scala version 2.13.8

API is using one of the class in Calculator. This is my build.sbt

```
name := "sbt-getting-started"

ThisBuild / version := "1.0"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.8"

publish/skip := true

lazy val api = project
  .dependsOn(calculators)
  .enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.apiDependencies
  )
  .settings(scalaVersion := "2.12.8")

lazy val calculators = project
  .enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
  .enablePlugins(DockerPlugin)
  .settings(
    scalaVersion := "2.13.8",
    libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.calculatorDependencies,
 )
```

As Compiled, I am getting the below error. Help me to resolve the issue.

```
←[0m[←[0m←[0minfo←[0m] ←[0m←[0mExecuting in batch mode. For better performance use sbt's shell←[0m
←[0m[←[0m←[0minfo←[0m] ←[0m←[0mUpdating api...←[0m
←[0m[←[0m←[31merror←[0m] ←[0m←[0mSERVER ERROR: Bad Gateway **url=https://dl.bintray.com/bala/maven/calculators/calculators_2.12/1.0/calculators_2.12-1.0.pom←[0m
←[0m[←[0m←[33mwarn←[0m] ←[0m←[0m        module not found: calculators#calculators_2.12;1.0←[0m**
←[0m[←[0m←[33mwarn←[0m] ←[0m←[0m==== local: tried←[0m
←[0m[←[0m←[33mwarn←[0m] ←[0m←[0m  C:\Users\Balachandar.S\.ivy2\local\calculators\calculators_2.12\1.0\ivys\ivy.xml←[0m
←[0m[←[0m←[33mwarn←[0m] ←[0m←[0m==== public: tried←[0m
←[0m[←[0m←[33mwarn←[0m] ←[0m←[0m  https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/calculators/calculators_2.12/1.0/calculators_2.12-1.0.pom←[0m
←[0m[←[0m←[33mwarn←[0m] ←[0m←[0m==== bintray-bala-maven: tried←[0m
←[0m[←[0m←[33mwarn←[0m] ←[0m←[0m  **https://dl.bintray.com/bala/maven/calculators/calculators_2.12/1.0/calculators_2.12-1.0.pom←[0m
←[0m[←[0m←[33mwarn←[0m] ←[0m←[0m        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::←[0m
←[0m[←[0m←[33mwarn←[0m] ←[0m←[0m        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::←[0m
←[0m[←[0m←[33mwarn←[0m] ←[0m←[0m        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::←[0m
←[0m[←[0m←[33mwarn←[0m] ←[0m←[0m        :: calculators#calculators_2.12;1.0: not found←[0m
←[0m[←[0m←[33mwarn←[0m] ←[0m←[0m        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::←[0m
←[0m[←[0m←[33mwarn←[0m] ←[0m←[0m←[0m
←[0m[←[0m←[33mwarn←[0m] ←[0m←[0m        Note: Unresolved dependencies path:←[0m**
←[0m[←[0m←[33mwarn←[0m] ←[0m←[0m                calculators:calculators_2.12:1.0←[0m
←[0m[←[0m←[33mwarn←[0m] ←[0m←[0m                  +- api:api_2.12:1.0←[0m
←[0m[←[0m←[31merror←[0m] ←[0m←[0msbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: calculators#calculators_2.12;1.0: not found←[0m
←[0m[←[0m←[31merror←[0m] ←[0m←[0m       at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.resolveAndRetrieve(IvyActions.scala:332)←[0m
```

Comment: **Scala** versions are not binary compatible between them, so no you can't use a class from another module if such module is not compiled to the same **Scala** version.

Comment: What I should do, if each module depends on different version of Scala library

Comment: Nothing, you simply can't do anything. You need to migrate all modules to the same **Scala** version or don't interact between modules. - Another option may be to create a third module that can be cross-compiled across all **Scala** versions and all other modules will depend on this third one instead of between them.